# How to realloc an array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory, struct

Using c, I'm trying to input stuff into an array of structs, and once that array is filled, double the size of the array and keep going, using realloc.

I know there's been several question like this asked already, but I was hoping someone could explain it clearly since I didn't create my array the way those questions did and am getting a bit confused.

I have a struct

```
struct Data {
    // Some variables
}
```

and initialised the array using

```
struct Data entries[100];
int curEntries = 100;
int counter = 1; // index, I use (counter - 1) when accessing
```

To realloc, I'm currently using

```
if(counter == curEntries){  // counter = index of array, curEntries = total
    entries = realloc(entries, curEntries * 2);
}
```

I know I need to cast realloc to something right? I'm just not sure how or what I'm meant to be casting it to, so I currently don't have anything, which of course gives me the error "assignment to expression with array type"

Thanks!

Comment: The type you are handling is `struct Data`. Try casting to it like so: `entries = (struct Data *) realloc((struct Data *) entries, curEntries * 2);`

Comment: Furthermore, I have seen this commonly paired with `malloc` (allocating in the heap instead of the stack). Why are you not using it?

Comment: Arrays can not be `realloc`. `struct Data entries[100];` --> `struct Data *entries = malloc(100 * sizeof *entries);`

Comment: Hmm, that casting didn't work, but the answer below seemed to be the way to do it . . .

As for using malloc, I wasn't sure what the difference was when first initialising, don't they do the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct Data entries[100];// memory is already allocated to this
```

You need to declare `entries` as pointer like:

```
struct Data *entries=NULL;
entries = malloc(curEntries  * sizeof(struct Data));
//When its time to reallocate
entries = realloc(entries, (curEntries * 2 * sizeof(struct Data)));
```

Comment: The idiom `old_ptr = realloc(old_ptr, new_size)` is a memory leak waiting to happen.  The correct idiom is `new_ptr = realloc(old_ptr, new_size); if (new_ptr == NULL) { …handle out of memory error… } old_ptr = new_ptr;`.

Comment: how is that a memory leak could you elaborate?

Comment: @programmerc3981143 `realloc()` can return `NULL` on failure. In this case you are overwriting the pointer to your dynamically allocated memory with `NULL`. Thus, you are unable to `free()` it later on. This can be prevented by storing the result of `realloc()` in a new pointer and only assign it to the old pointer after you have checked that it is in fact not `NULL`.